# Joining a List<String> inside a map

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to convert a `Map<String, List<String>>` to a `Map<String, String>`, where the value for each key is the joint string built by joining all the values in the `List` in the previous map, e.g.:

```
A -> ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
B -> ["one", "two", "three"]
```

should be converted to

```
A -> "foo|bar|baz"
B -> "one|two|three"
```

What's the idiomatic way to do this using the Java 8 Streams API?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use [`Collectors.joining(delimiter)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-) for this task.

```
Map<String, String> result = map.entrySet()
                                .stream()
                                .collect(toMap(
                                    Map.Entry::getKey, 
                                    e -> e.getValue().stream().collect(joining("|")))
                                );
```

In this code, each entry in the map is collected to a new map where:

- the key stays the same
- the value, which is a list, is collected to a `String` by joining all the elements together

Answer (score 43):

Simply use [`String.join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Iterable-), no need to create the nested stream:

```
Map<String, String> result = map.entrySet()
                            .stream()
                            .collect(toMap(
                                e -> e.getKey(), 
                                e -> String.join("|", e.getValue())));
```

Answer (score 7):

Google Guava has a nice helper method for this:

```
com.google.common.collect.Maps.transformValues(map, x -> x.stream().collect(joining("|")));
```

using pure java, this would work:

```
map.entrySet().stream().collect(toMap(Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().stream().collect(joining("|"))));
```

Comment: It should be noted that `Maps.transformValues` does not create an independent verbatim map, but a view of original map instead.